# How to fix Opera and Google Chrome?

Tags: linux-mint, chrome, opera

Recently I've changed from mint 17 to linux mint 18. Unlike on mint 17, now Google Chrome border is like it is not selected (light-gray color) and returns

```
[WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED
```

this error, and has some graphical problems, while playing screen sections are turning black for some seconds.

I also installed Opera, it doesn't have any visual issues, but terminal shows

```
[0927/131635:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(583)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.UPower.Device'

[WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED

Vector smash protection is enabled.

[0927/131637:ERROR:ticl-message-validator.cc(212)] registration_digest must be non-empty

[0927/131637:ERROR:ticl-message-validator.cc(319)] field registration_summary failed validation in { protocol_version: { version: { major_version: 3 minor_version: 2  }  } client_token: "NWqcVMArVrn/FjkzTOaZ4A==" registration_summary: { num_registrations: 0 registration_digest: ""  } server_time_ms: 0  }

[0927/131637:ERROR:ticl-message-validator.cc(361)] field header failed validation in { header: { protocol_version: { version: { major_version: 3 minor_version: 2  }  } client_token: "NWqcVMArVrn/FjkzTOaZ4A==" registration_summary: { num_registrations: 0 registration_digest: ""  } server_time_ms: 0  }  }

[0927/131637:ERROR:protocol-handler.cc(145)] Received invalid message: { header: { protocol_version: { version: { major_version: 3 minor_version: 2  }  } client_token: "NWqcVMArVrn/FjkzTOaZ4A==" registration_summary: { num_registrations: 0 registration_digest: ""  } server_time_ms: 0  }  }
```

What does this errors mean and how can they be fixed?